# Does a stationary process implies a normal distribution of the data?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, heteroscedasticity

My understanding is 'no', a stationary process does not imply a normal distribution of the data. However I haven't found a clear indication in my library or online. I am interested in other resources comparing stationary and heteroscedastic processes to data distributions.

I understand a stationary process joint probability distribution does not change over time. But does it necessarily mean that the *shape* of the distribution is normal?

Comment: As far as I can see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) answers your questions, as would any time series analysis text.

Comment: @Conjugate Prior You clearly know this field better than i do, but I'm not finding the answer on that page, nor any mention of "normal" or "Gaussian."  I also don't recall seeing a time series text that addresses it.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: **Hint**: Let $\{X_i\}$ be a sequence of iid random variables with distribution $F$. Is the process $\{X_i\}$ stationary?

Comment: @ConjugatePrior That's one of the first resources I looked at. But all I read there is that a stationary process has constant mean and variance over time. It doesn't mean the distribution of the outcomes is normal.

Comment: @cardinal Yes to your question. But let's reverse the question: the sequence of ${X_i}$ shows stable mean and variance over time. Does it mean the overall distribution is normal?

Comment: Can you think of any other $F$ that satisfy that? Start simple, but then ask yourself the question, when is what you say *not* true? Further still, does $F$ even need to *have* a mean or variance for $\{X_i\}$ to be (strictly) stationary in my example? Hopefully this will push your thinking a bit.

Comment: @cardinal Let's say $F$ is slightly leptokurtic, so it doesn't match the canonical normal shape. I will have a few outliers up and down in the plotted data over time. Does it mean the variance is not constant? Nope, if the outliers are evenly distributed over time than the variance (and mean) will not significantly change.

Comment: Robert, what does the shape of $F$ have to do with stationarity in the example I gave? I think you may be confusing some concepts of [stationarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) with those of [ergodicity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodicity).

Comment: @cardinal By shape of $F$ I actually mean the shape of the data. I look at the shape of the data to see if it is normally distributed. The original question is: does a stationary time-series imply a normal distribution of the data? And my understanding is no, it doesn't. Why not to give me a clear cut answer with a short explanation and then I will take it from there to see why I am wrong?

Comment: cardinal already answered: any iid process is stationary, without requirement on the instantaneous distribution $F$

Comment: Robert, I did not mean to cause frustration. I usually prefer to interact directly with people at first. Oftentimes, this process is more effective for learning than simply posting the answer. It encourages both the OP and myself to think things through more carefully. I can try to post an answer in a bit, but it would likely be in the form of addressing the broader question of the meaning of the various definitions of stationarity and the common misconceptions that appear to arise repeatedly about them on this site. Cheers. :)

Comment: @cardinal I appreciate how you are following up my comments but honestly I still don't understand what your answer is. I keep reading that an iid sequence is stationary, but my question is quite a different one and I don't think it can be easily derived from the previous fact.

Comment: Hi, Robert. Yes, the point was (intentionally) slightly vague to allow you to think it through a bit. The more explicit version is this: A sequence of iid random variables is stationary for ***any*** distribution $F$ (not just normal). This shows immediately that stationarity does *not* imply normality. (We have a whole *class* of counterexamples!) Does that make clearer how your question and my comments are related?

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way to construct a counterexample is to contemplate any transformation $f$ that, when applied to any Normal variable, gives a non-Normal distribution.  Applying $f$ to a stationary Normal process then does the trick, quite trivially, because all the requirements for stationarity obviously hold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a discussion about this on dsp.SE some months ago.  [My answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/488/235) there might help resolve some of the issues that the OP has.

**Added in response to @Alexis's complaint:**

*In part*, what I said there is as follows:

- *All* the random variables in the process have identical CDFs: $F_{X(t_1)}(x) = F_{X(t_2)}(x)$ for all $t_1, t_2$.
- *Any two* random variables separated by some specified amount of time have the same joint CDF as *any other* pair of random variables separated by the *same* amount of time.  For example, the random variables $X(t_1)$ and $X(t_1 + \tau)$ are separated by $\tau$ seconds, as are the random variables $X(t_2)$ and $X(t_2 + \tau)$, and thus $F_{X(t_1), X(t_1 + \tau)}(x,y) = F_{X(t_2), X(t_2 + \tau)}(x,y)$
- Any *three* random variables $X(t_1)$, $X(t_1 + \tau_1)$, $X(t_1 + \tau_1 + \tau_2)$ spaced $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ apart have the same joint CDF as $X(t_2)$, $X(t_2 + \tau_1)$, $X(t_2 + \tau_1 + \tau_2)$ which as also spaced $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ apart. Equivalently, the joint CDF of $X(t_1), X(t_2), X(t_3)$ is the same as the joint CDF of $X(t_1+\tau), X(t_2+\tau), X(t_3+\tau)$
- and similarly for *all* multidimensional CDFs.

Effectively, the probabilistic descriptions of the random process do not depend on what we choose to call the origin on the time axis: shifting all time instants $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_n$ by some fixed amount $\tau$ to $t_1 + \tau, t_2 + \tau, \ldots, t_n + \tau$ gives the same probabilistic description of the random variables.   This property is called *strict-sense stationarity* and a random process that enjoys this property is
called a strictly stationary random process or, more simply, a stationary random process. Be aware that in some of the statistics literature (especially the parts related to econometrics and time-series analysis), stationary processes are defined somewhat differently; in fact as what are described later in this answer as *wide-sense stationary* processes.

> **Note that strict stationarity by itself does not require any particular form of CDF.**  *For example, it does not say that all the variables are Gaussian.*

Later in the same answer, I say about *wide-sense-stationary* (or WSS) random processes a.k.a. weakly stationary stochastic (or WSS) processes....

> Note that the definition says nothing about the CDFs of the random variables comprising the process; it is entirely a constraint on the first-order and second-order moments of the random variables.

Thus once again, there is nothing in the definition of stationary processes (in the time series folks' meaning of the word) that requires the random variables to be normally distributed,

Comment: (+1) That is an excellent answer and addresses nearly all the main points that one would wish to know. It is fortuitous for the OP that you've specifically addressed his concern, as well. There is *one* point that has appeared here repeatedly that may, or may not, come up in the DSP community. Several times here, I have seen people make the statement to the effect that *because the mean and variance are constant in time*, the process is wide-sense stationary. While the converse is true, the one stated is not; ignoring the invariance of the autocorrelation seems to be a common misunderstanding.

Comment: Your answer on DSP.SE is excellent, but this is more or less a link-only answer, and I feel it could benefit from some... ah... *added caloric content* here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the time-series process $\{ X_t | t \in \mathbb{Z} \}$ with IID binary outcomes with marginal probabilities:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_t = 0) = \mathbb{P}(X_t = 1) = \tfrac{1}{2}
\quad \quad \quad \text{for all } t \in \mathbb{Z}.$$

Is this process (weakly or strongly) stationary?  Is the data from this process normally distributed?

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

For a counterexample, consider drawing $iid$ observations from a non-normal distribution, such as $exp(1)$. The distribution does not change over time (drawing from `rexp` in R or `np.random.exponential` in Python is the same whether you do it today or tomorrow), so the process is stationary, but the distribution is not normal.